# Calculate Time Remaining

Tags: c#, algorithm

What's a good algorithm for determining the remaining time for something to complete?  I know how many total lines there are, and how many have completed already, how should I estimate the time remaining?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Why not?

<strike>`(linesProcessed / TimeTaken)`</strike> `(timetaken / linesProcessed) * LinesLeft = TimeLeft`

`TimeLeft` will then be expressed in whatever unit of time `timeTaken` is.

## Edit:

Thanks for the comment you're right this should be:

`(TimeTaken / linesProcessed) * linesLeft = timeLeft`

so we have

`(10 / 100) * 200` = 20 Seconds now 10 seconds go past
`(20 / 100) * 200` = 40 Seconds left now 10 more seconds and we process 100 more lines
`(30 / 200) * 100` = 15 Seconds and now we all see why the copy file dialog jumps from 3 hours to 30 minutes :-)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here.  Say we processed 100 lines over 10 seconds, with 200 lines left.  That gives us (100/10)*200 = 2000 seconds left.  Now 10 seconds pass with no more lines processed.  Now, time left is (100/20)*200 = 1000 seconds left even though no more processing has occurred.

Comment: the expression should be (TimeTaken/linesProcessed)*linesLeft

Comment: Yea the expression was wrong;-) But it was right in the spirit of things!

Comment: Sometimes, when your brain shuts off, its nice to find someone who pointed out the obvious answer (only not so obvious after a long day hacking).  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should take also in mind what's in the first comment.  Fixing what it says: Say we processed 100 lines over 10 seconds, with 200 lines left. That gives us (10/100)*200 = 20 seconds left. Now 10 seconds pass with no more lines processed. Now, time left is (20/100)*200 = 40 seconds left even though no more processing has occurred.  From my point of view, one should recalculate the time left at each iteration, taking into account not the whole program history, but the last N time/records. KR

Comment: What your trying to do is calculate the Avg(TimePerIteration) * IterationsLeft, Looking at just the last iteration isn't sufficent in my opinion, you'd want to take the average across the most recent iterations. This might help when calculating time for a process that has a lot of latency like network operations so if you have a slow period then it speeds, the slow period won't skew the results. It's also possible the progress bar is on a separate UI thread so you want to be able to update the bar seperate from your iterations

Answer (score 36):

I'm surprised no one has answered this question with code!

The simple way to calculate time, as answered by @JoshBerke, can be coded as follows:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
for (int index = 0, count = lines.Count; index < count; index++) {
    // Do the processing
    ...

    // Calculate the time remaining:
    TimeSpan timeRemaining = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).Ticks * (count - (index+1)) / (index+1));

    // Display the progress to the user
    ...
}
```

This simple example works great for simple progress calculation.
However, for a more complicated task, there are many ways this calculation could be improved!

For example, when you're downloading a large file, the download speed could easily fluctuate.  To calculate the most accurate "ETA", a good algorithm would be to only consider the past 10 seconds of progress.  Check out [**ETACalculator.cs**](http://github.com/scottrippey/Progression/blob/master/Progression/Extras/ETACalculator.cs) for an implementation of this algorithm!

**ETACalculator.cs** is from  [**Progression**](http://github.com/scottrippey/Progression)  -- an open source library that I wrote.  It defines a very easy-to-use structure for all kinds of "progress calculation".  It makes it easy to have nested steps that report different types of progress.  If you're concerned about Perceived Performance (as @JoshBerke suggested), it will help you immensely.

Comment: This is actually a pretty good library. I think if you create a NuGet package for it, it might get popular.

Comment: please create a NuGet Package

Comment: Sorry, I'm about 7 years out-of-date with my .NET experience.  I'd be happy to add collaborators to the project, or even transfer ownership, if you'd like to contribute to the project and help create the NuGet package :)

Answer (score 19):

Make sure to manage [perceived performance](http://blog.codinghorror.com/actual-performance-perceived-performance/).

> Although all the progress bars took exactly the same amount of time in the test, two characteristics made users think the process was faster, even if it wasn't:
>
> 1. progress bars that moved smoothly towards completion
> 2. progress bars that sped up towards the end

Comment: Yeah, I read that post.  And I felt the effects of what he was talking about too.  Copying felt REALLY slow in Vista, but apparently because of the progress bar and not the actual time it took.

Comment: I agree Disgruntled.  It's much better in Windows 7, much like everything else in Windows 7.

Answer (score 16):

Not to revive a dead question but I kept coming back to reference this page.
You could create an extension method on the Stopwatch class to get functionality that would get an estimated remaining time span.

```
static class StopWatchUtils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets estimated time on compleation. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sw"></param>
    /// <param name="counter"></param>
    /// <param name="counterGoal"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static TimeSpan GetEta(this Stopwatch sw, int counter, int counterGoal)
    {
        /* this is based off of:
         * (TimeTaken / linesProcessed) * linesLeft=timeLeft
         * so we have
         * (10/100) * 200 = 20 Seconds now 10 seconds go past
         * (20/100) * 200 = 40 Seconds left now 10 more seconds and we process 100 more lines
         * (30/200) * 100 = 15 Seconds and now we all see why the copy file dialog jumps from 3 hours to 30 minutes :-)
         * 
         * pulled from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473355/calculate-time-remaining/473369#473369
         */
        if (counter == 0) return TimeSpan.Zero;
        float elapsedMin = ((float)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000) / 60;
        float minLeft = (elapsedMin / counter) * (counterGoal - counter); //see comment a
        TimeSpan ret = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minLeft);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
int y = 500;
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
for(int x = 0 ; x < y ; x++ )
{
    //do something
    Console.WriteLine("{0} time remaining",sw.GetEta(x,y).ToString());
}
```

Hopefully it will be of some use to somebody.

EDIT:
It should be noted this is most accurate when each loop takes the same amount of time.

Edit 2:
Instead of subclassing I created an extension method.

Comment: kudos for the idea of implementing a simple solution like extension method

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you know three things at any point in time while processing:

1. How many units/chunks/items have been processed up to that point in time (A).
2. How long it has taken to process those items (B).
3. The number of remaining items (C).

Given those items, the *estimate* (unless the time to process an item is constant) of the remaining time will be

B * C / A

Comment: Which time to process can never trully be constant can it? the difference might be negligable especially on small batches, but you can't control the system outside of your own app, plus it wouldn't be constant btw different hardware.

Comment: The issue on hardware changing is irrelevant, as you're the CURRENT run for this equation, and presumably the hardware doesn't change by too much between lines 10 and 11.

Answer (score 3):

I made this and it works quite good, feel free to change the method signature according to your variable types or also to the return type, probably you would like to get the TimeSpan object or just the seconds...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the eta.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="processStarted">When the process started</param>
    /// <param name="totalElements">How many items are being processed</param>
    /// <param name="processedElements">How many items are done</param>
    /// <returns>A string representing the time left</returns>
    private string CalculateEta(DateTime processStarted, int totalElements, int processedElements)
    {
        int itemsPerSecond = processedElements / (int)(processStarted - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds;
        int secondsRemaining = (totalElements - processedElements) / itemsPerSecond;

        return new TimeSpan(0, 0, secondsRemaining).ToString();
    }
```

You will require to initialize a `DateTime` variable when the processing starts and send it to the method on each iteration.

Do not forget that probably your window will be locked if the process is quite long, so when you place the return value into a control, don't forget to use the `.Refresh()` method of it.

If you are using threads then you can attempt to set the text using the `Invoke(Action)` method, would be easier to use [this extension method to archieve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738767/backgroundworker-cross-thread-operation-not-valid/19540412#19540412) easily.

If you use a console application, then you should not have problems displaying the output line by line.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I get a divided by zero at itemsPerSecond = ... My processStart is 23:53:26 and my DateTime.Now is 23:53:28. Why division by zero?

Comment: Hi Daniel, the TimeSpan (result of adding or substracting DateTime objects) probably has a difference of "Zero" seconds. According to your values it should be "2" seconds.. please verify the value of the "Ticks" to ensure it is different between "processStarted" and DateTime.Now

Answer (score 2):

It depends greatly on what the "something" is.  If you can assume that the amount of time to process each line is similar, you can do a simple calculation:

```
TimePerLine = Elapsed / LinesProcessed
TotalTime = TimePerLine * TotalLines
TimeRemaining = TotalTime - LinesRemaining * TimePerLine
```

Comment: Just a little Edit: TimeRemaining = (TotalTime - LinesRemaining) * TimePerLine

Answer (score 1):

there is no standard algorithm i know of, my sugestion would be:

- Create a variable to save the %
- Calculate the complexity of the task you wish to track(or an estimative of it)
- Put increments to the % from time to time as you would see fit given the complexity.

You probably seen programs where the load bar runs much faster in one point than in another. Well that's pretty much because this is how they do it. (though they probably just put increments at regular intervals in the main wrapper)

Answer (score 1):

Where `time$("ms")` represents the current time in milliseconds since 00:00:00.00, and `lof` represents the total lines to process, and `x` represents the current line:

```
if Ln>0 then
    Tn=Tn+time$("ms")-Ln   'grand total of all laps
    Rn=Tn*(lof-x)/x^2      'estimated time remaining in seconds
end if
Ln=time$("ms")             'start lap time (current time)
```

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on what is being done... lines are not enough unless each individual line takes the same amount of time.

The best way (if your lines are not similar) would probably be to look at logical sections of the code find out how long each section takes on average, then use those average timings to estimate progress.

Comment: They probably won't take the same amount of time, but I really just want to estimate the remaining time.  I know it won't be 100% accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the percentage completed, and you can simply assume that the time scales linearly, something like

timeLeft = timeSoFar * (1/Percentage)

might work.

Answer (score 0):

I already knew the percentage complete & time elapsed, so this helped me:

TimeElapsed * ((100 - %complete) / %complete) = TimeRemaining

I then updated this value every time %complete changed, giving me a constant varying ETA.

Comment: It should be `TimeElapsed / Percent * 100.0`

Comment: Alireza: No, it shouldn't. That gives you the estimated duration of the entire process, not the time remaining.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways of showing time

1. Time elapsed and Time Remaining overall:
   so elapsed will increase but remaining will be likely stable total time needed (if per second is stable)
2. Time elapsed and Time Left:
   so Time Left = Total Needed - Elapsed

My idea/formula is more likely like this:

Processed - updated from running thread from 0 to Total

I have timer with 1000ms interval that calculates processed per second:

```
processedPerSecond = Processed - lastTickProcessed;
lastTickProcessed = Processed;  //store state from past call
```

processedPerSecond and lastTickProcessed are global variables out of timer method

Now if we would like to get how many seconds is required to complete the processing (in ideal constant assumption)
totalSecondsNeeded = TotalLines / PerSecond

but we want to show case 2. TimeLeft so
TimeLeftSeconds = (TotalLines - Processed) / PerSecond

```
TimeSpan remaining = new TimeSpan(0, 0, (transactions.Count - Processed) / processedPerSecond);
labelTimeRemaining.Text = remaining.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

---

Of course TimeLeftSeconds will "jump" if PerSecond jumps, so if past PerSecond was 10 then 30 then back to 10, the user will see it.

There is a way to calculate average, but this may not show real time left if process speeds up at the end

```
int perSecond = (int)Math.Ceiling((processed / (decimal)timeElapsed.TotalSeconds));  //average not in past second
```

So it may be the choice for a developer to "pick" a method that will be most accurate based on prediction of how "jumpy" the processing is

We could also calculate and save each PerSecond, then take last 10 second and made average, but in this case user will have to wait 10 seconds to see first calculation
or we could show time left starting from first per second and then progressively average summing up to 10 last PerSecond

I hope my "jumpy" thoughts will help someone to build something satisfying

Answer (score 0):

How about this....

I used this to walk through a set of records (rows in an Excel file, in one case)

L is the current row number
X is the total number of rows
dat_Start is set to Now() when the routine begins

```
Debug.Print Format((L / X), "percent") & vbTab & "Time to go:" & vbTab & Format((DateDiff("n", dat_Start, Now) / L) * (X - L), "00") & ":" & Format(((DateDiff("s", dat_Start, Now) / L) * (X - L)) Mod 60, "00")
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell function

```
function CalculateEta([datetime]$processStarted, [long]$totalElements, [long]$processedElements) {
    $itemsPerSecond = $processedElements / [DateTime]::Now.Subtract($processStarted).TotalSeconds
    $secondsRemaining = ($totalElements - $processedElements) / $itemsPerSecond

    return [TimeSpan]::FromSeconds($secondsRemaining)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer ***System.Threading.Timer*** rather than *System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch*.

> System.Threading.Timer, which executes a single callback method on a
>   thread pool thread

The following code is an example of a calculating elapsed time with *Threading.Timer*.

```
public class ElapsedTimeCalculator : IDisposable
{
    private const int ValueToInstantFire = 0;

    private readonly Timer timer;
    private readonly DateTime initialTime;

    public ElapsedTimeCalculator(Action<TimeSpan> action)
    {
        timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(_ => action(ElapsedTime)));
        initialTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    // Use Timeout.Infinite if you don't want to set period time.
    public void Fire() => timer.Change(ValueToInstantFire, Timeout.Infinite);

    public void Dispose() => timer?.Dispose();

    private TimeSpan ElapsedTime => DateTime.UtcNow - initialTime;
}
```

BTW You can use System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler (scheduler.Now.UtcDateTime) instead of using DateTime directly, if you would like to mock and virtualize the datetime for unit tests.

```
public class PercentageViewModel : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ElapsedTimeCalculator elapsedTimeCalculator;

    public PercentageViewModel()
    {
       elapsedTimeCalculator = new ElapsedTimeCalculator(CalculateTimeRemaining))
    }

    // Use it where You would like to estimate time remaining.
    public void UpdatePercentage(double percent)
    {
        Percent = percent;
        elapsedTimeCalculator.Fire();
    }

    private void CalculateTimeRemaining(TimeSpan timeElapsed)
    {
        var timeRemainingInSecond = GetTimePerPercentage(timeElapsed.TotalSeconds) * GetRemainingPercentage;

        //Work with calculated time...  
    }

    public double Percent { get; set; }

    public void Dispose() => elapsedTimeCalculator.Dispose();

    private double GetTimePerPercentage(double elapsedTime) => elapsedTime / Percent;

    private double GetRemainingPercentage => 100 - Percent; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

First create a array with the time taken per entry, then calculate the remaining elements and calculate average time taken

```py
import datetime from datetime
import time

# create average function**
def average(total):
    return float(sum(total)) / max(len(total), 1)

# create array
time_elapsed = []

# capture starting time
start_time = datetime.now()

# do stuff

# capture ending time
end_time = datetime.now()

# get the total seconds from the captured time (important between two days)
time_in_seconds = (end_time - start_time).total_seconds()

# append the time to a array
time_elapsed.append(time_in_seconds)

# calculate the remaining elements, then multiply it with the average time taken
est_time_left = (LastElement - Processed) * average(time_elapsed)

print(f"Estimated time left: {time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(est_time_left))}")
```

** `timeit()` with `k=5000` random elements and `number=1000`

```py
def average2(total):
    avg = 0
    for e in total: avg += e
    return avg / max(len(total),1)

>> timeit average          0.014467999999999925
>> timeit average2         0.08711790000000003
>> timeit numpy.mean:      0.16030989999999967
>> timeit numpy.average:   0.16210096000000003
>> timeit statistics.mean: 2.8182458
```

Comment: From the tags on the question I think that it's about C# not python

Comment: It's also 12 years old, but I'm sure the idea holds across languages.