# BackgroundWorker - Cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform application (one form), on this form there is a RichTextBox. In the constructor of this form I create an instance of the class `MyClass`. In the “Form_Load” I call the method `Initialisation` from `MyClass` instance.

**In the form constructor**

```
myClass = new MyClass(RichTextBox richTextBox);
```

**In the Form_Load**

```
myClass.Initialisation();
```

In the `Initialisation` method, in a loop, I read some parmeters  do other stuffs. To not freeze the application (because some operation can take a while, some seconds), I use a `BackgroundWorker`. I use it like this (see code below).

When I execute, I get this error : *Cross-thread operation not valid: Control ‘richTextBox’
accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on*.

Could you tell me how solve this ? Work perfect when I don't access the `richTextBox`

```
public Class MyClass
{
    static BackgroundWorker _bw;
    public MyClass()
    {
        _bw = new BackgroundWorker
        {
            WorkerReportsProgress = true,
            WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
        };
        _bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        _bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
        _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }
    static void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (....)
        {
            if (....)
            {
                richtextBox.Text.AppendText("MyText");
            }
        }
        e.Result = true;
    }
    static void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e){}
    static void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e){}
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Using `BackgroundWorker` doesn't exempt you of the normal threading rules - such as that *only* the UI thread can access UI components.

If you want to update the UI from a `BackgroundWorker` *other than* using the progress/completion events (which are raised on the UI thread) you need to use [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) / [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) just as you would in other situations. For example:

```
if (....)
{
    Action action = () => richtextBox.Text.Add("MyText");
    richtextBox.Invoke(action); // Or use BeginInvoke
}
```

Answer (score 13):

try this code,

```
BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    richtextBox.Text.Add("MyText");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Using BackgroundWorker component, only the `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events allow you to invoke methods/properties on UI controls (which should be always done on UI thread). As you are updating the UI in `DoWork` event which runs on a non-UI thread you are getting this error, you should probably update you UI controls using Invoke or BeginInvoke methods in DoWork event if you want to.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this.

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
{
    richtextBox.Text.Add("MyText");
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

To make it cleaner and based on Jon Skeet's suggestion, I made an extension method which does the same, you can change the "`this Label control`" to `this TextBox control` or simply use "`this Control control`" (and basically allow every control to be updated easily):

```
internal static class ExtensionMethods
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the label text while being used in a multithread app.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="control">The control.</param>
    /// <param name="text">The text.</param>
    internal static void UpdateThreadedText(this Label control, string text)
    {
        Action action = () => control.Text = text;
        control.Invoke(action);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Refreshes the threaded.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="control">The control.</param>
    internal static void RefreshThreaded(this Label control)
    {
        Action action = control.Refresh;
        control.Invoke(action);
    }
}
```

And then the usage is quite simple:

```
this.yourLabelName.UpdateThreadedText("This is the text");
this.yourTextBoxName.UpdateThreadedText("This is the text");
this.yourControlName.UpdateThreadedText("This is the text");
```

or

```
this.yourLabelName.RefreshThreaded();
```

Works for me nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

i think the error stops on this line:

```
richtextBox.Text.Add("MyText");
```

your question i similar to this:

[BackgroundWorker OnWorkCompleted throws cross-thread exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818767/backgroundworker-onworkcompleted-throws-cross-thread-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
e.Result = "MyText";
```

In your `bw_DoWork`
And:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText((string)e.Result);
```

In your `bw_RunWorkerCompleted`

(Alter it to fit your code)

EDIT:

If it's done many times during the `BackgroundWorker`'s work, you can add:

```
_bw.ReportProgress(0, "MyText");
```

to the `bw_DoWork`
and:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText((string)e.UserState);
```

to the `bw_ProgressChanged`.